# Regex exact match with brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const str = 'Submission Date (Expected)';

const regex = new RegExp("^" + str + "$")

console.log(regex.test(str));

Output: FALSE
```

I'm using this site for testing:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

The goal is to compare string, EXACT MATCH. When I remove brackets from const str it returns TRUE but i need TRUE with brackets.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
const str = 'Submission Date \(Expected\)';
```

Comment: Use the function mentioned in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3082296). If you want to make the literal work as is, you need two slashes `\\(Expected\\)`

Comment: @adiga i tried this , still same OUTPUT

Comment: If `str` is the escaped string, test it against `'Submission Date (Expected)'` not against `str` again.

Answer (score 0):

Before using a bare string within regex, you need to escape it like explained in this question: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I did const str1 = escapeRegex(str) and console.log(regex.test(str1)); , still same output

Comment: @user3590094 Works fine: `const str = 'Submission Date (Expected)', str1 = escapeRegex(str), regex = new RegExp("^" + str1 + "$"); console.log(regex.test(str));`